# How to keep the order of the dict in a list when i sent from Flask to Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, flask

I have a big list that contains many dictionaries. In these dicts, there are keys and values.

Here is an example

```
[
    {'id': 'chart4', 
    'name': 'name', 
    'charts': ({'id': 'id', 'type': 'BarChart', 'values': {'max_slots': 0, 'avg_slots': 0, 'min_slots': 0}, 'title': 'title'}, 
        {'id': 'id', 'type': 'PieChart', 'values': {'name1': 0, 'name2': 0}, 'title': 'title'}, 
        {'id': 'id', 'type': 'BarChart', 'values': {'= 1': 0, '[1; 4]': 18, '[5; 8]': 0, '[9; 16]': 0, '[17; 32]': 0, '[33; 64]': 0, '[65; 128]': 0, '> 128': 0}, 'title': 'title'})}, 
    
    {'id': 'chart5', 
    'name': "name", 
    'charts': ({'id': 'id', 'type': 'BarChart', 'values': {'max': 0, 'avg': 0, 'min': 0}, 'title': "title"}, 
        {'id': 'id', 'type': 'PieChart', 'values': {'name1': 9, 'name2': 9}, 'title': "title"}, 
        {'id': 'id', 'type': 'BarChart', 'values': {'< 3600': 18, '[3600; 21600]': 0, '[21600; 43200]': 0, '[43200; 86400]': 0, '> 86400': 0}, 'title': "title"})}
]
```

This list is generated with Python 3.8

I have to keep this list in order

```
'values': {'= 1': 0, '[1; 4]': 18, '[5; 8]': 0, '[9; 16]': 0, '[17; 32]': 0, '[33; 64]': 0, '[65; 128]': 0, '> 128': 0}
```

To read this list i use a json

```
var charts = JSON.parse('{{ charts|tojson }}');
```

Once the list is parse, I have a list sorted by alpha/Num order cause it's json...

How can I keep this order, while keeping my list?

Comment: If you need a defined order, then use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different data structure. Instead of this:

```
'values': {
     '= 1': 0,
     '[1; 4]': 18,
     '[5; 8]': 0,
     '[9; 16]': 0, 
     '[17; 32]': 0,
     '[33; 64]': 0,
     '[65; 128]': 0,
     '> 128': 0
}
```

...use this:

```
"values": [
     [  1,   1,  0],
     [  2,   4, 18], 
     [  5,   8,  0],
     [  9,  16,  0],
     [ 17,  32,  0], 
     [ 33,  64,  0],
     [ 65, 128,  0],
     [129, 1e9,  0]
]
```

... where 1e9 is just some extreme value. You could also use `null` instead (`None` in Python).

As you can see, I prefer the more atomic data (separating in integers), as the titles seem to be derived from that. If you prefer, you can of course stick to the titles at the source:

```
"values": [
     ["= 1", 0],
     ["[1; 4]", 18],
     ["[5; 8]", 0],
     ["[9; 16]", 0], 
     ["[17; 32]", 0],
     ["[33; 64]", 0],
     ["[65; 128]", 0],
     ["> 128", 0]
]
```

Comment: I think an array should be the best solution, but '=1' is a name, not a value.

Comment: My understanding was that `=1` denoted an equality, so a range with just one possible value. In the second occurrence of `values` you have `< 3600` in that position, which seems to represent a range from the lowest possible value to 3599.

Comment: No, it is the title of a column, how many values correspond to =1 or > 128. we have the name and the value, the name will be used to display the graph. =1' is text

Comment: Then add the title as an extra element in subarrays. But it seems to be a title that can be dynamically generated from the range information.

Comment: I didn't want to complicate the task, so I went through a list, I separated my dictionary into several {key:value} dictionaries in a list. Since json keeps the index of each item in the lists then I don't have any problem. Thank you